# Parallel hyperplanes in $c_0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, convex-analysis

Consider $c_0$ – space real zero limit sequences. Let's consider $B_1(\bar{x})$ unit closed ball in $c_0$. Consider $H = \{x : f(x) = 0\}, $ where $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} 2^{-i} x_i$. We want to know if there is an supporting hyperplane in $B_1(\bar{x})$ with, which is parallel to $H$.

My attempt: suppose there is a supporting hyperplane which is parallel to $H$ (with supporting point $a$). Assume we consider unit ball centered in zero $\bar{0}$. Then $B_1(0) = \{\bar{x} \in c_0 : x_i \to 0 , |x_i| \le 1\}$, this means $f(x) \Big|_{B_1(0)} = (-1, 1)$. Hence, if there is a supporting hyperplane in $B_1(0)$, then  there should be $\bar{y} \in B_1(0)$ with $f(\bar{y}) = \bar{k} \in (-1, 1)$. But then since $(-1, 1)$ is open there is a $\tilde{k} > \bar{k}$ and $\bar{z} \in B_1(0) : f(\bar{z}) = \tilde{k}$ - contradiction.

Comment: Doesn't your attempt show also that there is no supporting hyperplane for the unit ball in $l^2$?

Comment: Regarding your question, yes, parallel hyperplanes are just two level sets of the same linear functional. But, I really don't follow your proof! Why is $f(-a) = -f(a)$ a contradiction? What do you mean by a "symmetric point"? Where did you use the definition of $f$?

Comment: @TheoBendit we have to $B_1(\bar{x}) \subset \{f(x) \ge k\}$ (for example). Hence, if $f(a) \ge k$, then $f(-a) = \sum 2^{-n} (-a_n) = - f(a) = -k$.

Comment: @openspace So, $-k \ge k$, so $k \le 0$. I still don't see a contradiction.

Comment: @TheoBendit editted!